# Service Worker fetch event not being called

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have the following code

**index.js**

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("/cache.js", {
    scope: "/",
  })
}
```

**cache.js**

```
const cacheName = "app";

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      return fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      }).catch(() => {
        return cache.match(event.request);
      });
    }),
  );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", () => {
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(
        [
          "/",
          "/index.js",
          "/index.css",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/favicon.ico",
        ],
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Every event gets called without an error except for `fetch` which does not get called at all. I am doing this all over https. Anyone have an idea why this is not working? I have looked at many relevant posts and they have only gotten me this far.